# How to convert dynamic and unique rows to columns?

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress

I fill the Devexpress grid as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVVys.jpg)
I want to convert Period rows data as columns like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qenmu.jpg)
By the way, the Period column is unique, but the count of records may change, so the count of columns to convert may also change accordingly.
In this case, I guess I need to define the column names runtime.
How can I do this conversion?
Thans in advance.

Comment: See this link: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1009299/pivotgrid-how-to-swap-row-and-column-fields-in-code

Comment: I don't believe it makes sense to "convert" rows to columns like this. What is the reason behind this design decision? Are you sure this is the proper approach?